# How to install xgap 4.30 in Ubuntu using the terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, package, gap-system

I tried to install xgap in terminal and I have already gap 4.10.2 on my system. However I am getting following problem:

```
root@heino-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/xgap-4.30# /home/heino/Schreibtisch/gap-4.30/  
bash: /home/heino/Schreibtisch/gap-4.30/: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden  
root@heino-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/xgap-4.30# ./configure --with-gaproot=/home/heino/Schreibtisch  /gap-4.10.2  
checking for make... make  
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu  
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu  
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu  
checking for gcc... gcc    
checking whether the C compiler works... yes  
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out  
checking for suffix of executables...   
checking whether we are cross compiling... no  
checking for suffix of object files... o  
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes  
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes  
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89...   needed  
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes  
checking for CONFIGNAME... none  
checking for GAP root directory... /home/heino/Schreibtisch/gap-4.10.2  
checking for GAP architecture... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-default64-kv3  
configure: creating ./config.status  
config.status: creating Makefile  
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `xgap.sh.in'
```

I am Math student and I have no idea about programming in Linux. How can I install xgap4.30 package in Ubuntu?

Comment: A valid `xgap-4.30.tar.gz` provides `xgap-4.30/xgap.sh.in` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qO7-2WH4JDNr1mSzL5lbaDJziCy8eB6o/view?usp=sharing ... ( Extracted from the Fedora 31 source package = `xgap-4.30-3.fc31.src.rpm` ).

Comment: Have you managed to install it? If you installed GAP from https://www.gap-system.org/Releases/, it should be already there, and no need to download it separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [xgap-4.30.tar.gz](https://gap-packages.github.io/xgap/). Now go to the download folder where you have just download `xgap-4.30.tar.gz`. Now, open your terminal ad do following things as mentioned [here](https://fossies.org/linux/gap/pkg/xgap-4.30/README):

- tar xzvf xgap-4.30.tar.gz
- cd xgap
- ./configure
- make

Comment: Thank you so much.. I do it but when i do the  command make the following error are accured:

Comment: root@heino-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/xgap-4.30# make
( cd bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc ; make CC=gcc )
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/heino/Downloads/xgap-4.30/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc“ wird betreten
gcc -I. -g -O2   -o xcmds.o -c ../../src.x11/xcmds.c
In file included from ../../src.x11/xcmds.c:9:0:
../../src.x11/utils.h:134:13:

Comment: fatal error: X11/StringDefs.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
 #include    <X11/StringDefs.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:31: recipe for target 'xcmds.o' failed
make[1]: *** [xcmds.o] Error 1
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/heino/Downloads/xgap-4.30/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc“ wird verlassen
Makefile:47: recipe for target 'compile' failed
make: *** [compile] Error 2