# how to install xgap in ubuntu linux

Tags: linux

when i tried to install xgap in the terminal of linux there is an error accure in the step ((make)) as below:

```
root@heino-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/xgap-4.30# make  
( cd bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc ; make CC=gcc )  
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/heino/Downloads/xgap-4.30/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc“ wird   betreten  
gcc -I. -g -O2   -o xcmds.o -c ../../src.x11/xcmds.c  
In file included from ../../src.x11/xcmds.c:9:0:  
../../src.x11/utils.h:134:13: **fatal error: X11/StringDefs.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht   gefunden  
 #include <X11/StringDefs.h>**

compilation terminated.  
Makefile:31: recipe for target 'xcmds.o' failed  
make[1]: *** [xcmds.o] Error 1  
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/heino/Downloads/xgap-4.30/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc“ wird   verlassen  
Makefile:47: recipe for target 'compile' failed  
make: *** [compile] Error 2
```

so what should i do now? and what should i write which command after that to install the startup script?? 
thanks alots!

Edit: Highlighting

Answer (score 0):

( Also ref. the previous **xgap** question [How to install xgap 4.30 in Ubuntu using the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60047726/how-to-install-xgap-4-30-in-ubuntu-using-the-terminal) by @Elias ).

> fatal error: X11/StringDefs.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

Search for a file :

```
$ sudo apt install apt-file
$ apt-file update
$ apt-file search StringDefs.h
```

Install the library : `$ apt install libxt-dev`

Comment: I have already install it but when i do the command make the same error accured

Comment: Please check that `X11/StringDefs.h` is present on your OS : `$ ls /usr/include/X11/StringDefs.h` . .... Which Ubuntu version are you using : The OS specification is missing in your question.